Writing files to one folder using joblib
I have a function that performs a long run and then writes the result file to the output folder. I decided to parallelize this function using Parallel and delayed from joblib. That is, each thread will write its result with a unique name, but in a common folder for all threads. Will there be any problems in this case?
There were no errors or warnings during startups.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

it depends on the operating system, but all operating systems i know of are thread-safe, writing to two files in the same folder shouldn't cause any problems, but writing to the same file from two threads would be unsafe.

Hard to tell for me from what you give us in your question.
A code example would be helpful.
Some things to consider:

try it on a small sample that is representative for the whole workflow
consider overflowing ram in your implementation


There is no function, I want to understand in theory if there will be a problem? But conditionally let the function create an arbitrary matrix 512x512, give it an arbitrary name and write it to the shared output folder, and I want to do this operation on several processor threads.
